# removing duplicate elements in an array and also the elements which is repeated most in the array should come first in the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

const source = [2, 9, 9, 1, 6];

const ans = source.filter((item, index, arr)=> arr.indexOf(item) === index);

console.log(ans);

here i'm able to remove the duplicate elements but how to make 9 which is repeated highest to come first in the new array??
any help would be appreciated

ans should be [9, 2, 1, 6]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for all cases where array should be sorted by most number of reoccurrences.

```js
const source = [2,1,9,9,6];
const indexes = [];

var ans = source.filter((item,index,arr)=>{
    if(arr.indexOf(item) === index){
        indexes.push({item:item,count:1})
        
        return true;
    }
    else if(arr.indexOf(item) !== index){
        
        indexes[indexes.findIndex(object=> object.item === item)].count++
        return false;
    }
    return false;

})

ans =(indexes.sort((a,b)=>{return b.count - a.count}).map(obj =>obj.item))

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortAndFilter(source) {
    let duplicates = {};
    //count the duplications
    source.filter((item, index, arr) => {
        if(arr.indexOf(item) != index) 
            return duplicates[item] = (duplicates[item] || 0) + 1;
        duplicates[item] = 0;
    })
   //sort the numbers based on the amount of duplications
    return Object.keys(duplicates).map(a => parseInt(a)).sort((a, b) => duplicates[b] - duplicates[a]);
}
```

`Output: [ 9, 6, 2, 1 ]`

This could do the job

Comment: You should probably add some description as to how you've solved this and maybe some MDN links to methods you've used that might not be apparent to the OP (rather than just dumping some code. And perhaps use a snippet (`[<>]` in the edit tool bar) to make the code run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If using more `space` is okay, you can use a hash map for counting elements and then convert it to an array.

Something like this.

```js
let arr =  [2, 9, 9, 1, 6];
// count elements
const map = arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map());

// sort by values and convert back to array
const res = [...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0]).map((a) => {
    return a[0]
});


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function removeAndSort(arr) {
    var order = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var value = arr[i];
        if (value in order) {
            order[value]++;
        } else {
            order[value] = 1;
        }
    }
    var result = [];
    for (value in order) {
        result.push(value);
    }
    function sort(a, b) {
        return order[b] - order[a];
    }
    return result.sort(sort);
}

console.log(removeAndSort([2, 9, 9, 1, 6]));
```

It's Absolutely Working, Check It

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the duplicates with the code you have you need to find a way [to create a frequency map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to save the duplicates information. In this example I create a map using an object like this...

```
const freq = { 9: [9, 2], 1: [1, 1] ... };
```

which uses the current iterated element as a key in an object, and the value is the element along with its duplicate value. You can grab those arrays using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them by that duplicate value, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that sorted nested array to produce the result.

Note, however, due to the sorting process this results in `[9, 1, 2, 6]`.

```js
const source = [2, 9, 9, 1, 6];

// `reduce` over the array creating a key/value pair where
// the value is an array - the first element is the element value,
// and the second value is its duplicate value
const nested = source.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // If the object property as defined by the element
  // value doesn't exist assign an array to it initialising
  // the duplicate value to zero
  acc[c] ??= [c, 0];

  // Increment the duplicate value
  ++acc[c][1];

  // Return the object for the next iteration
  return acc;

}, {});

// We take the `Object.values` of the object (a series of
// nested arrays and sort them by their duplicate value,
// finally `mapping` over the sorted arrays and extracting
// the first element of each
const out = Object.values(nested).sort((a, b) => {
  return b[1] - a[1];
}).map(arr => arr[0]);

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

this is best answer for your question

```js
const source = [2, 9, 9, 1, 6];

function duplicate(array) {
  let duplicates = array.filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item) !== index);
  return duplicates.concat(array.filter((item) => !duplicates.includes(item)));
}

console.log(duplicate(source));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const source = [2, 9, 9, 1, 6];
  
  const ans = source.filter((item, index, arr)=> arr.indexOf(item) === index);

  ans.sort((a, b) => b-a);

  console.log(ans);
}
```

Output: `[ 9, 6, 2, 1 ]`

Comment: but bro with other random no the sort won't work i think

Comment: The code is meant to sort by order of how many duplicates there are, not by value.

Comment: right @Andy
the most number of duplicate element to come first in the new array

Comment: @AvilashChak does it matter if it's `[9,2,1,6]` or `[9,1,2,6]` as long as the first number is `9`?